# Try to implement consolibyte/quickbooks-php with QB Web connector

Tags: quickbooks

I try to implement example_web_connector via QB Web Connector
I added App to QBWC, password, authenticate passed, but QBWC got error "0x80045242: QBPOSXML: Unknown request version" 
In which side I must to "watch"?

1. QB POS 2013
2. QBSDK 13.0
3. QBC

   `<?xml version="1.0"?>
       <QBWCXML>
       <AppName>QB</AppName>
       <AppID>IDNTS_POS_1</AppID>
       <AppURL>http://localhost/</AppURL>
       <AppDescription>QB</AppDescription>
       <AppSupport>http://localhost/dashboard/</AppSupport>
       <UserName>test</UserName>
       <OwnerID>{A91CC425-ABC4-4972-9FC6-D5F6B90F0472}</OwnerID>
       <FileID>{349C0857-7A5D-428c-B0B9-E0AC9377EE14}</FileID>
       <QBType>QBPOS</QBType>
       <Style>Document</Style>
   </QBWCXML>`

   4. example code of index.php from http://localhost/

```
php

// I always program in E_STRICT error mode... 
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// We need to make sure the correct timezone is set, or some PHP installations will complain
if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
{
    // * MAKE SURE YOU SET THIS TO THE CORRECT TIMEZONE! *
    // List of valid timezones is here: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
}

// Require the framework
require_once 'quickbooks-php-master/QuickBooks.php';

$user = 'test';
$pass = 'test';

// Map QuickBooks actions to handler functions
$map = array(
    QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_add_request', '_quickbooks_customer_add_response' ),
    //QUICKBOOKS_ADD_SALESRECEIPT => array( '_quickbooks_salesreceipt_add_request', '_quickbooks_salesreceipt_add_response' ), 
    //'*' => array( '_quickbooks_customer_add_request', '_quickbooks_customer_add_response' ), 
    // ... more action handlers here ...
    );

// This is entirely optional, use it to trigger actions when an error is returned by QuickBooks
$errmap = array(
    3070 => '_quickbooks_error_stringtoolong',              // Whenever a string is too long to fit in a field, call this function: _quickbooks_error_stringtolong()
    // 'CustomerAdd' => '_quickbooks_error_customeradd',    // Whenever an error occurs while trying to perform an 'AddCustomer' action, call this function: _quickbooks_error_customeradd()
    // '*' => '_quickbooks_error_catchall',                 // Using a key value of '*' will catch any errors which were not caught by another error handler
    // ... more error handlers here ...
    );

// An array of callback hooks
$hooks = array(
    // There are many hooks defined which allow you to run your own functions/methods when certain events happen within the framework
    // QuickBooks_WebConnector_Handlers::HOOK_LOGINSUCCESS => '_quickbooks_hook_loginsuccess',  // Run this function whenever a successful login occurs
    );

$log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEBUG;              

$soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN;        // A pure-PHP SOAP server (no PHP ext/soap extension required, also makes debugging easier)

$soap_options = array(      // See http://www.php.net/soap
    );

$handler_options = array(
    //'authenticate' => ' *** YOU DO NOT NEED TO PROVIDE THIS CONFIGURATION VARIABLE TO USE THE DEFAULT AUTHENTICATION METHOD FOR THE DRIVER YOU'RE USING (I.E.: MYSQL) *** '
    //'authenticate' => 'your_function_name_here', 
    //'authenticate' => array( 'YourClassName', 'YourStaticMethod' ),
    'deny_concurrent_logins' => false, 
    'deny_reallyfast_logins' => false, 
    );      // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Server/Handlers.php file

$driver_options = array(        // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Driver/<YOUR DRIVER HERE>.php file ( i.e. 'Mysql.php', etc. )
    //'max_log_history' => 1024,    // Limit the number of quickbooks_log entries to 1024
    //'max_queue_history' => 64,    // Limit the number of *successfully processed* quickbooks_queue entries to 64
    );

$callback_options = array(
    );

$dsn = 'mysqli://root:@localhost/qb';

if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn))
{
    // Initialize creates the neccessary database schema for queueing up requests and logging
    QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);

    // This creates a username and password which is used by the Web Connector to authenticate
    QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn, $user, $pass);
}

$primary_key_of_your_customer = 5;

    $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $primary_key_of_your_customer);

$handler_options = array(), $driver_options = array(), $callback_options = array()

$Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level, $soapserver, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options, $driver_options, $callback_options);
$response = $Server->handle(true, true);

function _quickbooks_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{ 
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <CustomerAdd>
                        <Name>ConsoliBYTE, LLC (' . mt_rand() . ')</Name>
                        <CompanyName>ConsoliBYTE, LLC</CompanyName>
                        <FirstName>Keith</FirstName>
                        <LastName>Palmer</LastName>
                        <BillAddress>
                            <Addr1>ConsoliBYTE, LLC</Addr1>
                            <Addr2>134 Stonemill Road</Addr2>
                            <City>Mansfield</City>
                            <State>CT</State>
                            <PostalCode>06268</PostalCode>
                            <Country>United States</Country>
                        </BillAddress>
                        <Phone>860-634-1602</Phone>
                        <AltPhone>860-429-0021</AltPhone>
                        <Fax>860-429-5183</Fax>
                        <Email>Keith@ConsoliBYTE.com</Email>
                        <Contact>Keith Palmer</Contact>
                    </CustomerAdd>
                </CustomerAddRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';

    return $xml;
}

function _quickbooks_customer_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{   
    // Great, customer $ID has been added to QuickBooks with a QuickBooks 
    //  ListID value of: $idents['ListID']
    // 
    // We probably want to store that ListID in our database, so we can use it 
    //  later. (You'll need to refer to the customer by either ListID or Name 
    //  in other requests, say, to update the customer or to add an invoice for 
    //  the customer. 

    /*
    mysql_query("UPDATE your_customer_table SET quickbooks_listid = '" . mysql_escape_string($idents['ListID']) . "' WHERE your_customer_ID_field = " . (int) $ID);
    */
}

function _quickbooks_salesreceipt_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{   
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <SalesReceiptAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <SalesReceiptAdd>
                        <CustomerRef>
                            <FullName>Keith Palmer Jr.</FullName>
                        </CustomerRef>
                        <TxnDate>2009-01-09</TxnDate>
                        <RefNumber>16466</RefNumber>
                        <BillAddress>
                            <Addr1>Keith Palmer Jr.</Addr1>
                            <Addr3>134 Stonemill Road</Addr3>
                            <City>Storrs-Mansfield</City>
                            <State>CT</State>
                            <PostalCode>06268</PostalCode>
                            <Country>United States</Country>
                        </BillAddres>
                        <SalesReceiptLineAdd>
                            <ItemRef>
                                <FullName>Gift Certificate</FullName>
                            </ItemRef>
                            <Desc>$25.00 gift certificate</Desc>
                            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                            <Rate>25.00</Rate>
                            <SalesTaxCodeRef>
                                <FullName>NON</FullName>
                            </SalesTaxCodeRef>
                        </SalesReceiptLineAdd>
                        <SalesReceiptLineAdd>
                            <ItemRef>
                                <FullName>Book</FullName>
                            </ItemRef>
                            <Desc>The Hitchhiker\'s Guide to the Galaxy</Desc>
                            <Amount>19.95</Amount>
                            <SalesTaxCodeRef>
                                <FullName>TAX</FullName>
                            </SalesTaxCodeRef>
                        </SalesReceiptLineAdd>
                    </SalesReceiptAdd>
                </SalesReceiptAddRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';

    return $xml;
}

function _quickbooks_salesreceipt_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{   
    // Great, sales receipt $ID has been added to QuickBooks with a QuickBooks 
    //  TxnID value of: $idents['TxnID']
    //
    // The QuickBooks EditSequence is: $idents['EditSequence']
    // 
    // We probably want to store that TxnID in our database, so we can use it 
    //  later. You might also want to store the EditSequence. If you wanted to 
    //  issue a SalesReceiptMod to modify the sales receipt somewhere down the 
    //  road, you'd need to refer to the sales receipt using the TxnID and 
    //  EditSequence 
}

function _quickbooks_error_stringtoolong($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg)
{
    mail('your-email@your-domain.com', 
        'QuickBooks error occured!', 
        'QuickBooks thinks that ' . $action . ': ' . $ID . ' has a value which will not fit in a QuickBooks field...');
}
```

Also I installed only QB POS Server Workstation

Comment: Post your code. Post the .QWC file. Post the year/version/edition of QuickBooks you're using. We can't help you without all of this additional information.

Comment: update the post

Comment: So I think it's unlikely that you're going to get this to work with a 7-year-old version of QuickBooks POS. But -- can you put the Web Connector in VERBOSE mode, and then re-run it (or re-add the app), and post the logs?

Comment: Put QBWC in verbose mode, there is the link to logs:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RqD4F2AxCu2-hGga2NbRM1OtQIiIbqAfu48Fcd6VHKw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error message:

```
0x80045242: QBPOSXML: Unknown request version
```

Because you're sending requests for the wrong version. These requests:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
    <QBXML>
        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
            <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                <CustomerAdd>
```

Are for QuickBooks Pro/Premier/Enterprise. They are *not* QuickBooks *Point of Sale* requests at all. QuickBooks Point of Sale is a different product family than QuickBooks Pro/Premier/Enterprise.

The library you're using:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Has an example that is specifically for QuickBooks Point of Sale:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_point_of_sale.php

And you can see the requests are structured differently (and have different versions and XML headers):

```
// We're just testing, so we'll just use a static test request:
$xml = '
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbposxml version="3.0"?>
    <QBPOSXML>
        <QBPOSXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
            <CustomerAddRq>
```

You can also see the documentation here, which shows these requests:

https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/get-started/get-started-with-the-quickbooks-pos-sdk#download-and-install-the-quickbooks-pos-sdk

Comment: I install POS SDK 3.0 and update code in index.php to code from your example and now it works, Thanks!